# searching by title,category,like,dislike and date release

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to have a possibility to search a picture by title,category,like,dislike and date release . By title and category is working correct but by like and dislike always when I start by project default is value 0 and I see only picture which have value of like and dislike equal 0-I do not know how I can change this ,searching by date return all pictures

View->Index

```
<form asp-controller="Memy" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>

        <select asp-for="MemyCategory" asp-items="Model.Categorys">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
        Date: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchDate" />
        Like: <input type="number" asp-for="like" />

        Dislike: <input type="number" asp-for="dislike" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Controller and method which I responsible for this

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string memyCategory,
              string searchString, DateTime? searchDate,
              int? like, int? dislike)
    {
        // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
        IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in db.Memy
                                        orderby m.Category
                                        select m.Category;

        var memyy = from m in db.Memy
                     select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            memyy = memyy.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (like!=null)
        {
            memyy = memyy.Where(s => s.Like==like);
        }
        if (dislike != null)
        {
            memyy = memyy.Where(s => s.Dislike == dislike);
        }
        if (searchDate!=null)
        {
            memyy = memyy.Where(s => s.releaseDate.ToString().Contains(searchDate.ToString()));



        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memyCategory))
        {
            memyy = memyy.Where(x => x.Category == memyCategory);
        }

        var memyCategoryyy = new MemyCategoryViewModel
        {
            Categorys = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
            Memys = await memyy.ToListAsync()

        };

        return View(memyCategoryyy);
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple issues here, like and dislike are comparing to the same field (Like).  Your if condition only searches for dates if searchdate == null, need to be != null. Do you have a Dislike property?

Comment: I edited my post I changed what you wrote but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your Date compare could be modified as :

```
DbFunctions dfunc = null;
if (searchDate!= null)
{
    memyy = memyy.Where(s => SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions
            .DateDiffDay(dfunc, s.searchDate, searchDate) < 1);

}
```

For like/dislike , directly put checkpoint at server side and check whether get correct value(0/1) in Index function .